# How to run Multiple webView on single Layout/Page

Tags: android, webview

```
This is the main_activity.xml File
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        >
        <WebView
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/webView2"
             />
        <WebView
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/webView"
           />
    </LinearLayout>
```

And this is the MainActivity.java Code For the webView.

```
    WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView2);
    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.facebook.com");

    WebView myWebView1 = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    myWebView1.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
   myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
```

Whenever I am running the app only the webView2 is Working. How can i make both the webView run Simultaneously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your last line is loading into `myWebView` instead of `myWebView1`. It looks like you have a typo

Comment: Thanks, It was a typo.